# jquery search with :contains selector

Tags: jquery, database, search, anchor, contains

I am trying to make a simple search where my goal is to avoid any database calls as I am only searching in a specific list.

I am making a glossary where all words are displayed in a list with more info. 
Can I somehow use the :contains selector to go to the word the user had searched for, i.e: "rooftiles"

Like:

```
$("div:contains('rooftiles')");
```

Given my example I fill in "rooftiles" in the searchbox and if that word is found it will jump down to that word à la `<a name="rooftiles">`

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

Comment: Clear ambiguity about `searchbox`/ `anchor` and `div`. Post some `HTML`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#search').on('keyup', function(e) {
    // when user press enter
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var val = $.trim(this.value);
        if (val) {
            var target = $('div:contains(' + val + ')').first();
            if (target.length) {
                var top = target.position().top;
                $('body').animate({
                    scrollTop: top
                }, 500);
            }
        }
    }
});​
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xxQyQ/1/)***

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! SPOT ON! 

Thank you  :)

Comment: A question on this - how can I get it to select my div class named "word-header" that is inside to divs ("#all-words-box") and (".word-content-box).

When I just do $('div.word-header:contains(' + val + ')').first(); it do not scroll to the word header.

Comment: @MortenHagh it should not  happen... if possible make a fiddle and share the link

Answer (score 1):

In this case I'd suggest:

```
$('a[name*="rooftiles"]');
```

Or :

```
$('a[name~="rooftiles"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

If I well understood your question maybe you could

1. find the `div` containing the first occurence of `word`
2. Get its `offsetTop` value
3. Make the page scroll for the given amount

Something like

```
function jumpToWord(word) {
    var p = ($.browser.opera)? $("html") : $("html,body"),
        d = $("div:contains('" + word + "')").eq(0),
        offset = d.offset().top;
    p.animate({ scrollTop: offset }, 1000);
}
```

For the sake of accuracy, if your text is contained in shorter paragraphs, it's probably better search for

```
$("div p:contains('" + word + "')")
```